# How can I convert year, date, month to datetime?

Tags: pandas, datetime

For example, I have a column with data such as:

```
17.14.11
17.15.10
18.21.06
```

which is 2017-11-14, and I'd like to change this to a DateTime object such as:

```
2017-11-14
2017-10-15
2018-06-21
```

I tried to use pd.to_datetime but I think it doesn't recognize the above as a date.
How can I convert this using pandas' to_datetime function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check with `format` and `to_datetime`

```
pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format='%y.%d.%m')
```

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned its a column. And I tried your answer but it gave me an error of ```ValueError: time data '17.14.11' does not match format '%Y.%d.%m' (match)```